# fadeToggle Issue With jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to do a simple fadeToggle() with jQuery and for some reason the code isn't firing. I want clicking the link in the first `<li>` to make the other four list items appear.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <ul>
        <li><a id="filters-switch" href="javascript:void(0)">filters</a></li>
        <li class="filters"><a href="http://cargocollective.com/dzangtech/filter/event/">events</a></li>
        <li class="filters"><a href="http://cargocollective.com/dzangtech/filter/release/">releases</a></li>
        <li class="filters"><a href="http://cargocollective.com/dzangtech/filter/misc/">misc.</a></li>
        <li class="filters"><a href="http://cargocollective.com/dzangtech">all</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#filters-switch").click(function() {
  $(".filters").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
</script>
```

Also this is the website if it helps to look at that: http://cargocollective.com/dzangtech. The links are in the top-left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **jQuery v1.4.2**, apparently it doesn't feature `fadeToggle` - update to latest.

EDIT: yes, [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) comes in 1.4.4.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I am allowed.

Answer (score 2):

.fadeToggle() was added in jQuery 1.4.4--looks like your site is using jQuery 1.4.2. Try upgrading jQuery, otherwise you'll just need to just regular ol' fadeIn / fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

bind the event on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#filters-switch").click(function() {
    $(".filters").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
   });
});
```